# WIN10 Environment path variables not recognized when opening terminal from background context

Tags: windows-10, command-line, java, git, environment-variables

I installed Java RE and Git, for example, and made sure their binaries were added to Environment Path Variables under both User and System variables. When I launch a command prompt from the taskbar, these variables work properly (i.e. commands "java" and "git" are recognized.

I also added "open command window here" to background context by editing the registry. But when I open a command prompt using this method, my environment path variables aren't recognized.

How can I make the command prompt recognize my environment variables when opened this way?

Comment: Can you provide information on the registry key you added?  Also, have you logged off/on or restarted such that Explorer.exe has restarted.  I assume that the "cmd" window is inheriting the Explorer environment which doesn't yet have the new PATH variables.

Comment: Are there different users? Type `path` in either of the two CMD prompts to see if the Registry hack is leading to the wrong users, inheriting a different PATH (although the System PATH *should* be the same for both).

Comment: What's the reasoning for adding to both the user and system `PATH`?  Shouldn't it be one or the other if it's the same location that's being added?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the first comment made me realize I didn't restart explorer.exe. Doing so fixed the issue.

Comment: So I suggest to delete the question.